# What is the appropriate dependency for the equivalence of jakarta.json.JsonObject?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quarkus

I want to consume a quarkus route :

```
...
import jakarta.json.JsonObject;

@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/api/sites")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SiteResource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SiteResource.class);

    private final SiteService siteService;

    ...

    @Path("/{name}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        JsonObject apikey = siteService.getApiKeyByName(name);
        if (apikey == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();  
        }
        return Response.ok(apikey, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

In another project, a springboot one, I want to consume the `/api/sites/{name}` route ( with a provided value for the name parameter ) :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
JsonObject apiKeyObj = restTemplate.getForObject(urlSite, JsonObject.class);
```

Here is the pom.xml of the springboot project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.fnptechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>booking</name>
    <description>Booking Engine MAT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So what is the right dependency to add to match the quarkus JsonObject ?

Comment: Don't. Just use Jackson on a regular java object. You get JSON you don't need the classes from the server.

Comment: You can use ObjectNode from Jackson or JsonObject from Vertx, if Im not wrong.